# por que al ejecutar un script por ssh y comparar la respuesta en si me salta este error

Tags: python, linux, ssh

esto es lo que ejecuto con el script

```
import os, sys
cadena=os.system("ssh user@hana /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_BDH")

if (cadena.find('GREEN') != -1):
    print cadena
        sys.exit(0)
if (cadena.find('YELLOW') != -1):
        print cadena
        sys.exit(1)  
elif (cadena.find('GRAY') != -1):
        print cadena
        sys.exit(2)
else:
        print cadena
        sys.exit(3)
```

pero me dice lo siguiente

esto hace reperencia a lo que trae de el script

> Process hdbcompileserver, it's running in process ID : 12814 - process
>   status : GREEN,
>
> Process hdbcompileserver, it's running in process ID
>   : 12814 - process status : GREEN,

y me imagino yo que esto es lo que trae al comparar el if

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./check_BDH2", line 12, in
>   
>       if (cadena.find('GREEN') != -1): AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'find'

esto es lo que ejecutó el guión que estoy llamado

```
import os, sys

daemon1=os.popen("sapcontrol -nr 25 -function GetProcessList | grep hdbpreprocessor | awk '{print $1}'").readline().strip()
daemon2=os.popen("sapcontrol -nr 25 -function GetProcessList | grep hdbcompileserver | awk '{print $1}'").readline().strip()

status1=os.popen("sapcontrol -nr 25 -function GetProcessList | grep hdbpreprocessor | awk '{print $4}'").readline().strip()
status2=os.popen("sapcontrol -nr 25 -function GetProcessList | grep hdbcompileserver | awk '{print $4}'").readline().strip()

id1=os.popen("sapcontrol -nr 25 -function GetProcessList | grep hdbpreprocessor | awk '{print $11}'").readline().strip()
id2=os.popen("sapcontrol -nr 25 -function GetProcessList | grep hdbcompileserver | awk '{print $11}'").readline().strip()

if (status1 == "GREEN," and daemon1 == "hdbpreprocessor," and status2 == "GREEN," and daemon2 == "hdbcompileserver,"):
        print "Process %s it's running in process ID : %s - process status : %s." % (daemon2, id2, status2)
        print "Process %s it's running in process ID : %s - process status : %s." % (daemon2, id2, status2)
        sys.exit(0)

if (status1 == "YELLOW," and daemon1 == "hdbpreprocessor," and status2 == "YELLOW," and daemon2 == "hdbcompileserver,"):
        print "WARNING - Process %s is %s it's going up" % (daemon2, status2)
    print "WARNING - Process %s is %s it's going up" % (daemon2, status2)
        sys.exit(1)

elif (status1 == "GRAY" and daemon1 == "hdbpreprocessor," and status2 == "GRAY" and daemon2 == "hdbcompileserver,"):
        print "CRITICAL - Process %s is %s it's not going to go up" % (daemon2, status2)
    print "CRITICAL - Process %s is %s it's not going to go up" % (daemon2, status2)
        sys.exit(2)

else:
        print "UNKNOWN - %s is %s .We can not identify process status" % (daemon2, status2)
    print "UNKNOWN - %s is %s .We can not identify process status" % (daemon2, status2)
        sys.exit(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que lo que sucede es que tu esperas que `os.system` te devuelva lo que el comando escribe por la salida estándar... pero no. [`os.system`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-system-method/) te devuelve un entero que se corresponde con el código de error devuelto por el comando ejecutado.

> Return Value: On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process and on Windows, the return value is the value returned by the system shell after running command.

De ahí que el error te esté diciendo que `int` no tiene un método `find`:

```
if (cadena.find('GREEN') != -1):
#   ~~~~~~ ~~~~
#      int.find
```

Para recuperar la salida estándar tienes que usar `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess

cadena = subprocess.check_output("ssh user@hana /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_BDH", shell=True)
```